# Storing luggage in Casablanca for about 10 days

Tags: luggage-storage, morocco, casablanca

We are based in the USA, and are travelling to India for a wedding (4 days with multiple costumes, gifts, souvenirs, etc. --- so can't travel light). On the return route, we are stopping in Morocco for 10 days for some sightseeing (with a tour operator).

We are looking at luggage storage options and what we can do to store our fancy luggage for about 10 days somewhere in Casablanca. We do not want to lug this around Morocco. The tour operator and airline cannot store the luggage.

Are there options in the Casablanca airport, ONCF, or maybe an airline lounge which we can use for storing luggage (1, maybe 2 airline check-in bags)? Any experiences to share?

Comment: What's your price range? One option is to rent a cheap hotel room and dump your luggage there.

Answer (score 3):

There are luggage lockers in the [CTM bus station](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g293732-i9447-k8388915-CTM_bus_station-Casablanca_Grand_Casablanca_Region.html) but these *might* not be as large as you would like.

In general luggage storage in Casablanca became a particular problem after 2003 and it seems train stations may not have left luggage facilities.

Various people have, in the past, recommended [Supratours](http://www.supratours.ma/en/Contact) so it may be worth contacting them to find out what the current situation is.

Supratours have an affiliate that deals with post, cargo and storage. This seems not as geared up for the general public as most left luggage offices but might be what is required for larger luggage than will fit in 'normal' lockers. The company is [SMTR CARRE](http://www.carre.ma/).

[Casablanca Airport](http://www.casablanca-airport.com/concessions.php) offers a number of facilities but left luggage seems not to be included. On TripAvisor [Khamlia 29 March 2015, 10:09](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g293732-i9447-k7874088-12_hrs_layover_in_Casablanca_arpt_luggage_storage-Casablanca_Grand_Casablanca_Region.html)  advises:

> It is problem with luggage because at airport is not possible to store it.